# Python 3 variable reference in a string used for a PUT request

Tags: string, python-3.x, rest, payload

How do I reference python variables within a Rest API (payload) string? I can't get my script to recognize the value of the variables. For example:

```
import requests

var1 = "testId"
var2 = "testName"
var3 = "testUsername"
payload = "Id=var1&Name=var2&Username=var3"


# Desired output 
print(payload)
>>> Id=testId&Name=testName&Username=testUsername

# My output
print(payload)
>>> Id=var1&Name=var2&Username=var3
```

Based on the example above, the python script should get the values for var1, var2, and var3 (as opposed to printing the var string). Oddly enough I don't receive any error messages.

Comment: format your string, check this: https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create payload as a `dictionary`.

**Ex:**

```
import requests

payload = {'Id': "testId", 'Name': "testName", "Username":  "testUsername"}
res = requests.get('URL', params=payload)
```

**[MoreInfo:](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)**